# Using Circuit breaker pattern in Multi Threaded Environment

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am working on project which fetches the data from the `REST API` using `C#`. I am calling this in multi threaded fashion in a batch of 100 records at a time using `Parallel.ForEach`. I want to use a circuit breaker pattern when 2 requests in the 100 were failed due to connectivity error.

I have checked the [Poly Framework](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker) but did not get concrete examples of using the fault tolerant circuit breaker pattern in multi threaded scenarios(May I am missing those).

Any examples and frameworks to achieve this?
Any links for achieving this would bee very helpful.

Comment: All these fancy patterns!, for starters `Parallel.ForEach` shouldn't be used for IO bound operations. you are wasting resources and tying up threads. Secondly, `Parallel.ForEach` has no concept of a `timeout` (Circuit break pattern is now dead in the water), all you can do is use some sort of thread safe switch to shirt circuit residual processing. For thirds, you cant cancel a task that is not *cancellation-aware* (term i may have just made up) so what ever you are using hopefully should have a time out. lastly,

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @TheGeneral. I am hoping it should break even for any connectivity error. This should not specific to only time out.

Comment: You can spin up and start your own Tasks in a for loop. Tasks can be cancelled, and you can cancel them all if one or more Tasks fail in a certain way.

Comment: I was able to cancel the tasks and proceed as mentioned by MineR, But I have done the performance analysis of my code in the server and found that as TheGeneral mentioned it in comments it was indeed consuming quite a bit resources. So I have changed the code to call async and utilized the Polly's circuit breaker pattern on top of.

Thanks for all the comments.